# Create an msi for jre by using wix which is to install jre files in my package?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installscript-msi

I have jre files which are used by mypackage.msi. I want to create the jre.msi which is another msi called by mypackage.msi. mypackage.msi is created by using wix files. So please do help me in this... I need the wix script for the above mentioned.... My package uses install script as well but the files are called by wix....

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to call the jre.msi from within the mypackage.msi as you can only have one msi transaction running at once. Either place the jre files within the mypackage.msi or create a burn bootstrapper to chain the msi's together. Check the wix chm included on install of wix.

Comment: Without knowing what exactly you want to do in the jre.msi no. Do you need to install the JRE as a pre-requisite to your mypackage.msi? If so then read the section "Building Installation Package Bundles\Chain Packages into a Bundle
" in the wix manual for some help and create a ExePackage element that is the required version of the JRE you need.